# Add a wrapper in the header

Tags: custom-header

For, my configuration : 
Wordpress 4.3.1
Theme Nirvana 1.1.3

Main website : stra-tj DOT fr

My question seems to be quite easy asking it but I'm on it since 3 days and I don't know how to solve it.
I need to add in the header, at the right a wrapper from https://nutriqual.prestarest.fr/login , only the part with ID and password as shown in the picture bellow :

http://s29.postimg.org/ddrvu1nhz/part_needed.jpg

We need this part in the header, on the right side, with transparency so the background would not be hidden.

All websites are hosted on our servers
We can make a login2 webpage without any picture if this can help and give a better render.

The problem is that I really don't know how to proceed...
Can you please give me a hand ?

Don't mind to explain as if I was really dumb, I won't feel insulted and it will be easier for me or anyone else with the same issue.

Thanks a lot.

Emmanuel

Comment: From question it looks like you are not developer. If so, you can hire a professional to get job done quickly and accurately.

Comment: Its not really clear what you need.  Are you trying to add a login form on the right side of your header?

Comment: @Mike that's exactly what I want. I need to add a login form on the right side of my header. I've already done a few sites with Wordpress but I don't know how to fulfill this request...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<?php wp_login_form(); ?>` to output a login form.  Try editing your header.php file and adding this there.  Then, use CSS to align it to the right side of the header.